# Управление DNS на хостинге, для доменов зарегистрированных в другом месте

Tags: домен, dns

Многие хостинг компании в личном кабинете предлагают функцию управления dns доменами зарегистрированными в другом месте.

Допустим у меня есть сайт site.ru. И есть аккаунт у хостера host.net. Прописав их dns ns1.host.net я смогу управлять доменом через свой личный кабинет на host.net.

Вопрос: А если есть два аккаунта у host.net. Один из них мой другой злоумышленника. Я прописываю у сайта днс ns1.host.net.  Привязываю домен site.ru в панели host.net, а злоумышленник может и раньше чем я добавляет мой сайт также через панель host.net.

Кто в итоге управляет настоящими записями dns для site.ru ? Или такая ситуация невозможна?

Answer (score 1):

Ситуация *теоретически* возможна, если host.net непродуманный, кривой и т.п. И другой злоумышленник, и сами программисты host.net вполне могут намеренно или непреднамеренно сделать с зоной управляемого ими доменом что угодно (но не перепродать домен, и не сменить владельца).

Поэтому обычно владение доменом надо доказать в рамках вашего аккаунта на host.net
На примере [pdd.yandex.ru](https://pdd.yandex.ru/) — требуется сначала «Подтвердить домен», и лишь потом вы получаете возможность править файл зоны для этого домена.

Comment: host.net не просит проверки и добавить я могу какой угодно сайт хоть ya.ru, и он так и будет там висеть))